Reading a Text File (M code) from a SharePoint Document Library
The code below is able to read a text file which contains M syntax and loads it into Power Query. I would like to upload the text file in a SharePoint Document Library for others to use the M syntax. I think I need to replace File.Contents with SharePoint.Contents, but I don't know what else I would need to add to SharePoint.Contents. Can you please give me an example?
let
//Load M code from text file
Source = Text.FromBinary(File.Contents("C:\Users\maste\OneDrive\Desktop\Multiply.txt")),
//Evaluate the code from the file as an M expression
EvaluatedExpression = Expression.Evaluate(Source, #shared)
in
EvaluatedExpression
